# emacs command window is too small

Tags: window, doom, help

When I C-x to show the list of commands, the window of commands is chopped like below

[image]

how can I make it show the full?

Comment: `C-x` all by itself, in a default installation of Emacs without any user configuration, does not bring up any window with possible commands.  `C-x` is a prefix that will cause Emacs to wait for the next user input; i.e., a combination of keys that begins with the prefix ....

Comment: What @lawlist said. Please provide the steps you use to reproduce what you see, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). And please specify your Emacs version (release).

Comment: Shown is doom emacs. Emacs version is 28.2

Comment: I get this behaviour when I increase the font in doom emacs.  So far have not been able to find a fix.  Frame Max Height setting doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking at `which-key-mode`, which is not technically part of Doom Emacs, just something it installs and turns on for you. Like any good Emacs package, `which-key` provides a number of customizable settings. To see them, run `M-x customize-group` and enter `which-key` when prompted.

In particular, look for the “Which Key Frame Max Height” setting, which defaults to 20. The mode does not always use that many lines; after a quick skim of the code I see that it has some complicated adaptive behavior. I think it tries to divide the available keys up into pages of roughly equal size, though I’m not very sure. You may need to read the source code yourself, or examine the settings more carefully, or [contact the author directly](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key).

Answer (score 0):

C-h to see the help-row at the bottom. It should n for next, p for previous.